# How to retrieve exact string matching of records using mysql query?

Tags: mysql

This is my table.

```
create table t (name varchar(100));

insert into t values ('35,12');
insert into t values ('35');
insert into t values ('35,56');
insert into t values ('46,56');
insert into t values ('23,12');
```

If i'm search the records 35,56 it returns exact matching record but i want to retrieve 35 and 56 fall on all records. I'm passing value through in php variable like $test='35,56'.

I want to retrieve the output is:

```
35,12
35
35,56
46,56
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`select name FROM t WHERE name LIKE '35%' OR name LIKE '%,56%';`

+-------+

| name  |

+-------+

| 35,12 |

| 35    |

| 35,56 |

| 46,56 |

+-------+

```
`$test = "35,56";
    $keys = explode(',', $test);
    $query = "select name FROM t WHERE name LIKE '".$keys[0]."%' OR name LIKE '%,".$keys[1]."%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     $cnt = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo $array['name'].'<br>';
    }`
```

Comment: It will give u exactly what u ask

Comment: I'm passing value through in php variable $test='35,56'. Now how i can call it in a query?

Comment: but this code is wrong. If the name were '56,35' this would not really work when testing for 56, if you name was '320,561' this expression would also be true.

Answer (score 0):

,,MySQL has a function for that: `find_in_set()`

```
SELECT t.name FROM t
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('35',t.name) + FIND_IN_SET('56',t.name) > 0
```

This will test EXACTLY for the number 35 of 56, no matter in what sequence they are in the name column. If you have more than two numbers in the name column, this also works. If you test for '56' and the name column contains 156, this query will not be true.

To make it this safe with the `LIKE` expression would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT name FROM t
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('35',name) 
 or FIND_IN_SET('56',name)
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37535/14)

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT name FROM t
WHERE name LIKE '35,%' OR t LIKE '%,56'
```

Comment: I'm passing value through in php variable $test='35,56'. Now how i can call it in a query?

Comment: Why is first clause using `name` and second using `t`?